# how to edit multiple word in textview in android

Tags: android, textview

I want to bold multiple words from textview's text.
I am having words in array that i want to bold in textview's text.
how to do it by SpannableStringBuilder??

**My array:**

> string[] array =
>   {"Life","happiness","sadness","tears","smiles","laughter","emotions"};

**My Textview text:**

> **Life** is filled with **happiness**, **sadness**, **tears**, **smiles**, **laughter** and
>   other **emotions** but when life gets you down, just be strong about it
>   and keep your head up high and have faith in all things in life.

I go through [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828182/spannablestringbuilder-to-create-string-with-multiple-fonts-text-sizes-etc-examp) and other but not found any solution which i want.

```
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String[] list = new String[] { "Life","happiness","sadness","tears","smiles","laughter","emotions"};    

    String textData ="Life is filled with happiness, sadness, tears, smiles, laughter and other emotions but when life gets you down, just be strong about it and keep your head up high and have faith in all things in life";
    CharSequence cseq = "";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < list.length ; i++)
    {
          cseq = setSpanBetweenTokens(textData, list[i] , new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC));
    }
    text.setText(cseq.toString()); 


public static CharSequence setSpanBetweenTokens(CharSequence text,
            String token, CharacterStyle... cs)
        {
            // Start and end refer to the points where the span will apply
            int tokenLen = token.length();
            int start = text.toString().indexOf(token) + tokenLen;
            int end = text.toString().indexOf(token, start);

            if (start > -1 && end > -1)
            {
                // Copy the spannable string to a mutable spannable string
                SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
                for (CharacterStyle c : cs)
                    ssb.setSpan(c, start, end, 0);

                // Delete the tokens before and after the span
                ssb.delete(end, end + tokenLen);
                ssb.delete(start - tokenLen, start);

                text = ssb;
            }

            return text;
        }
```

Comment: <YOURTEXTVIEW>.setText(array[0] + " is filled with " + array[1] + " " array[2] ... (and so on)
?

Comment: @Myth1c but i want to do it dynamically. through SpannableStringBuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try as using Html.fromHtml:

```
string[] array = {"Life","happiness","sadness",
"tears","smiles","laughter","emotions"};

String strtemp="";
    for(int i=0;i<array.length-2;i++){
     if(i<array.length-3)
       strtemp+="<b>"+array[i]+",<b/>";
      else{
       strtemp+="<b>"+array[i]+"<b/>";
     }
    }
    txtview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
    txtview.setText(Html.fromHtml("YOUR_TEXT HERE"+strtemp+
             "YOUR_TEXT HERE <b>"+array[array.length-1]
                     +"</b> YOUR_TEXT HERE"));
```

Comment: thanks @ρяσѕρєя K but my textview text is not static.. its dynamic.. so i want to check that array values available in string if available then bold it.

Comment: @ArchanA : have you try it see my edit answer which is running with static TextView

Comment: @ArchanA : if it not work with dynamic TextView then use SpannableStringBuilder

Comment: @ArchanA : `not get perfect output` means can you share some relevant code then we will try

Comment: @ArchanA: what result you are getting using your current code ? can it's possible to show an image of current output?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you have a `TextView` that has some dynamic text in it, and you want to bold certain words in it. Try something like this:

```
Spannable sb = new SpannableString(textFromTextView);
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
    sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),
        textFromTextView.indexOf(array[i]), 
        array[i].length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

then call the setText() function of your textview with sb as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code:

```
 textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+array[0]+"</b>"+ "is filled with "+"<b>"+array[1]+"</b>"+","+"<b>"+array[2]+"</b>"+","+"<b>"+array[3]+"</b>"+","+"<b>"+array[4]+"</b>"+","+"<b>"+array[5]+"</b>"+"and other"+"<b>"+array[6]+"</b>"+"but when life gets you down, just be strong about it and keep your head up high and have faith in all things in life."));
```

Comment: I dont want as you suggest me I want like iterate loop till array length and if that word found in that will formated like wise.. Understand ??

Comment: then place the above line in if condition - check till the array.length() and array[i]!=null....