# how to bold a part of text Android String

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i want to bold a part of "" a text but i dont know how this my text:

```
<string name="apropos"> Le projet Marocherche : Bâtir au cœur d un portail professionnel, destiné aux entreprises marocaines, une création  conçue par des "professionnels pour des professionnels".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SpannableStringBuilder` and `new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD)` to format a part of the string to be **Bold**. You can get help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828182/spannablestringbuilder-to-create-string-with-multiple-fonts-text-sizes-etc-examp)

Answer (score 7):

Just use like this -

```
String sourceString = "<b>" + id + "</b> " + name; 
mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));
```

If you want to edit string in strings.xml, you can do it as -

```
<resource>
<string name="styled_welcome_message">We are <b>so</b> glad to see you.</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: What didn't you understand?

Comment: when i do like this : <resource> <string name="styled_welcome_message">We are <b>so</b> glad to see you.</string> </resources> he ingore the last part of text to see you. he dont show the last part –

Comment: can you show the string on which, you are testing that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<b>` and `</b>` tags in a string resource (along with their `<i>` and `<u>` counterparts). Depending on where and how you use the string resource, the formatting will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html format like below:

```
String str = "You are about to start a video consultation with Dr. "+doctor.lastname()+", press <b>Ok</b> to proceed"; 
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(str);
```