# Changing font style / format inside a string array in android

Tags: java, android, xml, fonts

I'm currently working on my first app - no experience in java or android so please have patience with me :)

In the app I'm using a custom list view with text only and 4 text views in each list item/container.

With these text views I'm using a custom font (applied using java in the listview adapter).

The font is loaded in assets/fonts
Text is fetched from a string array in strings.xml

I have figured all this out so far using all the Q&A's on this website however can't seem to find a solution for the following...

I want to change the style of my text (which has the custom font) during the paragraph/sentence. I want to highlight specific words or phrases in Italics for example:

I *enjoy* coding.

The word *enjoy* is Italics where the rest of the sentence is in Regular format.

I've seen plenty of guides on how to change a whole class or text-view into italics or bold styles however not specific portions of text.

So far the only possible solution I've found is to try italic markers in strings.xml however this doesn't seem to work and I don't know why

I'm assuming what I need to do is:
1. load the italic version of the font separately in java 
2, then write some code that tells the app to apply this font to specific portions of text, either in strings xml or some other way. (preferably in strings xml as there is alot of text)

Your help is much appreciated, Many thanks in advance.

Apologies if my explanation is too brief its my first post.

my code: (if you need anything else let me know.)

the main activity

custom listview adapter

main xml layout

row xml layout

```
public class WirdActivity extends Activity {

MediaPlayer mp;
String[] Arabic;
String[] Transliteration;
String[] Translation;
String[] Number;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wird);
    Resources res=getResources();
    Arabic=res.getStringArray(R.array.wirdarabic);
    Transliteration=res.getStringArray(R.array.wirdtransliteration);
    Translation=res.getStringArray(R.array.wirdtranslation);
    Number=res.getStringArray(R.array.wirdnumber);





    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wird);



    Button playwird = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playwird);
    playwird.performClick();
    playwird.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {


            mp.start();

        }


    });
    ImageButton pausewird = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pausewird);

    pausewird.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {


            mp.pause();

        }


    });


    ListAdapter theAdapter = new Wirdadapter(this, Arabic, Transliteration, Translation, Number);
    final ListView wirdlist  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wirdlist);
    wirdlist.setAdapter(theAdapter);






    }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {


    super.onDestroy();
    mp.stop();

}




class Wirdadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private AssetManager assets;

Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
        "fonts/trado.ttf");
Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
        "fonts/JaghbUni-Rom.ttf");

String[] titleArray;
String[] descriptionArray;
String[] subtitleArray;
String[] numberArray;



public Wirdadapter(Context context, String[] titles, String[] desc,String[] sub,String[] num) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_layout_3, R.id.textview2,titles);
    this.titleArray=titles;
    this.descriptionArray=desc;
    this.subtitleArray=sub;
    this.numberArray=num;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {





    LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    View theView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_3, parent, false);

    TextView Arabic = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
    TextView Transliteration = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.transliteration);
    TextView Translation = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.translation);
    TextView Number = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.number);

    Arabic.setText(titleArray[position]);
    Transliteration.setText(descriptionArray[position]);
    Translation.setText(subtitleArray[position]);
    Number.setText(numberArray[position]);

    Arabic.setTypeface(font);
    Transliteration.setTypeface(font2);
    Translation.setTypeface(font2);
    Number.setTypeface(font2);

    return theView;


}



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="5000pt"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_background3"
tools:context=".WirdActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#927e68"

>
<TextView
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/wird_title"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:id="@+id/wirdtitle"
/>
<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/pausewird"
    android:background="@drawable/pause"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginEnd="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/playwird"

    />
<Button
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/playwird"
    android:background="@drawable/play"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/wirdtitle"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17.5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />





</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="515dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/w1"
        android:id="@+id/wirdhead"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <ListView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="4100dp"
       android:id="@+id/wirdlist"
       android:gravity="right"
       android:divider="#f1f1f1"
       android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
>

   </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:textColor="#4c4c4c">

</TextView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview2"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#4c4c4c">

</TextView>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/transliteration"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"

    android:textColor="#4c4c4c">

</TextView>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/translation"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:textColor="#4c4c4c">

</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work for you
But as per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5169604/1750013

You can either try using spannable string or if text is pre-determined, define various strings in your xml, and then can try to concatenate them

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response,I copied and pasted the code and it worked but how do I apply it to the specific items of the string array?

Comment: Here :http://androidcocktail.blogspot.de/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html

it shows how you can set start and end index for span. With this you can specify the start and end of a particular text style

Comment: Solved it!
Your link put me on a big hunt, many forums later....
I used HTML code and it works exactly how I want it to:
In the adapter I inserted the following:

        String text =subtitleArray[position];
        Translation.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

Then in the strings.xml I added the following on the <Item> that i wanted:

<Item>  <![CDATA[   <i>   example text   </i>  ]]> </item>

Will write it up as an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `SpannableStringBuilder` class or the `Html.fromHtml()` method. The simpler one is the `Html.fromHtml()` method.

Example:

```
tView.setText(Html.fromHtml("I <i>enjoy</i> coding"));
```

The `Html.fromHtml()` method basically returns a SpannableString, but I usually find it easier than using the `SpannableStringBuilder` class.

That being said, if you want to modify the String dynamically, then you need to use the `SpannableStringBuilder` class.

**Note:**
I have not tried the `fromHtml()` method on an XML string resource, but do try it and share the results.

**PS:**
If you are really curious about SpannableString class, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828182/spannablestringbuilder-to-create-string-with-multiple-fonts-text-sizes-etc-examp%20'here%22) for a simple example or [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) for the full documentation.