# How to replace String of TextView without losing its style and color

Tags: android, textview, spanned

I set HTML mode to my TextView so in my text some String is blue or green. Now I need replace "old" to "new" without losing blue and green color. If use from `textview.setText(textview.getText().toString().repaceAll("old", "new"))`, we lose its style and color! In fact I need code that preserves the styles. Or I need replace String in Spanned without losing its style and color.

1. I need replace String in Spanned obj
2. I need set Spanned obj to my TextView. But I don't know any way.

Comment: if you setText(Spanned obj) // is it still losign style and color?

Comment: @notTdar No, First: I need replace string in Spanned obj so Second: I need set Spanned obj to my textview. but I don't know any way.

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828182/spannablestringbuilder-to-create-string-with-multiple-fonts-text-sizes-etc-examp?

Comment: No, it does not work for me @notTdar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

old string is `oldstr` and new string is `newstr`

```
    Spanned spanned = textView.getText();
    
    CharSequence charSequence = spanned;
    SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = (SpannableStringBuilder) spanned;

    for (int i = 1; i < charSequence.length() - 6; i++) {
        if (charSequence.charAt(i) == 'o' &&
                charSequence.charAt(i+1) == 'l' &&
                charSequence.charAt(i+2) == 'd' &&
                charSequence.charAt(i+3) == 's' &&
                charSequence.charAt(i+4) == 't' &&
                charSequence.charAt(i+5) == 'r') {
            stringBuilder.replace(i-1, i+6, "newstr");
        }
    }

    spanned = stringBuilder;
    textView.setText(spanned);
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way I could think of is using `SpannableStringBuilder`. A `Spannable` is a `CharSequence` and `textview.getText()` returns a `CharSequence` too. If you avoid the `toString` conversion the style will not be lost. SpannableStringBuilder has also a [replace](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int)) function

Comment: I solved my problem with your guidance and I wrote true code. thank you very much.